# Enable Doc Values on the mapping/template?

Tags: elasticsearch

Running ES 1.5.2

So I know we can set doc values per field, but is there a way to just tell ES to default all "not_analyzed" fields to doc values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None that I know of. You could define a dynamic template where, for any *new fields* in that index (fields that are not already defined in the static mapping of the index), to set them to use `doc_values`:

```
"dynamic_templates": [
   {
      "string_fields": {
         "mapping": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string",
            "doc_values": true
         },
         "match": "*",
         "match_mapping_type": "string"
```

but there is no way to match fields that are `not_analyzed` and automatically to consider them to use `doc_values`.

For ES 2.0, though, [`doc_values` are planned to be enabled by default](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8312).